# Django ManyToManyField with through -- how can I not lose data not selected in the QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

Django Newbie here. I have some trouble with a ManyToMany relationship and a through field.

I am trying to create a tool where staff members can apply for shifts on events (Bar, entry control, etc.). Therefore I created a Staff object (this is the person with all her roles etc.) and linked it by ManyToManyField to a ScheduledShift object (which contains event date, time and duties).

I want to be able to present each day as a view to the user where he/she can just tick the shifts he/she is available that day. This works and it also writes the correct data (i.e. records with the staff id and the shift id for all the shifts he/she ticked) for that day into the "through" table of the StaffShift class.

The relevant code looks like this:

models.py

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    ...
    shifts = models.ManyToManyField(ScheduledEventShift, through='StaffShift')

class StaffShift(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shift = models.ForeignKey(ScheduledEventShift, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
class StaffShiftUpdateView(ObjectUpdateView):
    model = Staff
    ...
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class=self.form_class)
        day = datetime(self.kwargs.get('year'), self.kwargs.get('month'), self.kwargs.get('day'))
        form.fields['shifts'].queryset = ScheduledEventShift.objects.filter(
 event__event_date=day).order_by('event__event_date')
        return form
```

('event' is a property in the ScheduledEventShift object)

My problem is that when saving the form all other already existing rows for that user that were not selected for the form's queryset (i.e. all other shifts that he/she has already ticked for other days) are removed in the through db table. This might be intended orm behaviour, but in my case the desired behaviour would be that records stay in the through table unless "their" day is shown in the form and they are unticked there.

What is the best way to keep those records in the through db table that were not selected in the queryset for the form?

One thing that I figured out that seems to work is getting all StaffShifts for that user that are not on that day before the form.save() and recreating them after the form.save():

```
def form_valid(self, form):
       
    other = StaffShift.objects.filter(staff__user__id=self.request.user.id).exclude(shift__event__event_date=day)
    form.save(commit=True)
    for o in other:
        StaffShift.objects.update_or_create(admin_confirmed=o.admin_confirmed, staff_shift_info=o.staff_shift_info,
                                                shift_id=o.shift_id, staff_id=o.staff_id)
    ...
```

As this feels more like a hack than a proper way to do things... Is there any better way to do that? It also doesn't seem to be efficient once there are many many shifts in the db ;-)

Comment: Hi hitby, I think you need to use CreateView instead of UpdateView, you can try that out and let me know if that works or not

Comment: hi @DhruvAgarwal thanks for replying... unfortunately this didn't work:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: users_staff.user_id.
Apart from that can I really use a Create View when I want to edit something again?